# Worksheet change event for every sheet in the workbook

Tags: vba, excel, events

Is there a way to globally install a change event that triggers on every single sheet?

I have a workbook with 52 sheets and I want to have the same event handler triggered. A central module with the code would help to manage the Trigger code but I don't want to add the code to every single sheet.

Is there a way to do it? Implementing it in the workbook module didn't Trigger anything.

Comment: You should use `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` , it works like the Sheet_Change event except that instead of `Me.`, you'll use `Sh.` to describe the sheet that trigger the event! ;)

Comment: That seems to work, you want to put that down as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Workbook_SheetChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196611.aspx) event macro. The *Sh* is the [Worksheet Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx) being passed in and the *Target* is the cell or cells that have received the change. A simple [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) should be enough to localize teh worksheet receiving the change.

A simple timestamp event might look like this.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    With Sh
        If Not Intersect(Target, .Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
            On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Dim rng As Range
            For Each rng In Intersect(Target, .Columns(1))
                rng.Offset(0, 4) = Now
            Next rng
        End If
    End With
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Any change made to a cell in column A of any worksheet will result in the current datetime being put into column E of the same worksheet and row. A newly created worksheet will immediately be affected. You can parse the worksheets affected by their Worksheet [.CodeName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx) or Worksheet [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx). The [Worksheet.Index property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836415.aspx) is not recommended unless you lock the workbook structure so that the worksheets cannot be reordered.

Answer (score 3):

You should use  :

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
```

It works like the `Sheet_Change` event except that instead of `Me.`, you'll use `Sh.` to reference the sheet that triggered the event.