# in all worksheets, on double click color cell

Tags: excel, vba, colors, double-click

how to implement this code to work on all worksheets in workbook.`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A2:A100")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Interior.ColorIndex
            Case xlNone, 4: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
            Case 45: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            Case Else: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

`

Comment: This question has a similar premise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33340448/worksheet-change-event-for-every-sheet-in-the-workbook

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Worksheet change event for every sheet in the workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33340448/worksheet-change-event-for-every-sheet-in-the-workbook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement that, you can use `Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick`. Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("A2:A100")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Interior.ColorIndex
            Case xlNone, 4: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
            Case 45: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            Case Else: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.