# Converting Worksheet VBA to all Sheets

Tags: excel, vba, module

I am trying to take some code is functioning on a single sheet and convert it so that it applies to all worksheets in the book. I thought I could move the code a module and then use the Workbook_SheetChange "wrapper" described in [Worksheet change event for every sheet in the workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33340448/worksheet-change-event-for-every-sheet-in-the-workbook). However, the Multiple Select dropdown still only works on the original sheet, despite the "Named_Range" being defined on all sheets.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    With Sh
        Dim OldVal As String
        Dim NewVal As String
    
        ' If more than 1 cell is being changed
        If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
        If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("Named_Range")) Is Nothing Then
            ' Turn off events so our changes don't trigger this event again
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            NewVal = Target.Value
            
            ' If there's nothing to undo this will cause an error
            On Error Resume Next
            Application.Undo
            On Error GoTo 0
            OldVal = Target.Value
            ' If selection is already in the cell we want to remove it
            
            If InStr(OldVal, NewVal) Then
                'If there's a comma in the cell, there's more than one word in the cell
                If InStr(OldVal, ",") Then
                    If InStr(OldVal, ", " & NewVal) Then
                        Target.Value = Replace(OldVal, ", " & NewVal, "")
                    Else
                        Target.Value = Replace(OldVal, NewVal & ", ", "")
                    End If
                Else
                    ' If we get to here the selection was the only thing in the cell
                    Target.Value = ""
                End If
            
            Else
                If OldVal = "" Then
                    Target.Value = NewVal
                Else
                    ' Delete cell contents
                    If NewVal = "" Then
                        Target.Value = ""
                    Else
                        ' This IF prevents the same value appearing in the cell multiple times
                        ' If you are happy to have the same value multiple times remove this IF
                        If InStr(Target.Value, NewVal) = 0 Then
                            Target.Value = OldVal & ", " & NewVal
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
                
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular modules don't have events. They are host agnostic. The [SheetChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbook.SheetChange) event is in the workbook object. So this means you must place your code into the `ThisWorkBook` object.

[image]

Now looking at your code I see a `With Sh` block that does nothing. You never use that object. The only place where it makes sense to use the sheet object is where you cite `ActiveSheet`. We always want to use `Sh` and we never want to assume that the correct sheet is active.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim OldVal As String
    Dim NewVal As String

    ' If more than 1 cell is being changed
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("Named_Range")) Is Nothing Then
        ' Turn off events so our changes don't trigger this event again
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        NewVal = Target.Value
        
        ' If there's nothing to undo this will cause an error
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.Undo
        On Error GoTo 0
        OldVal = Target.Value
        
        ' If selection is already in the cell we want to remove it
        If InStr(OldVal, NewVal) Then
            'If there's a comma in the cell, there's more than one word in the cell
            If InStr(OldVal, ",") Then
                If InStr(OldVal, ", " & NewVal) Then
                    Target.Value = Replace(OldVal, ", " & NewVal, "")
                Else
                    Target.Value = Replace(OldVal, NewVal & ", ", "")
                End If
            Else
                ' If we get to here the selection was the only thing in the cell
                Target.Value = ""
            End If
        Else
            If OldVal = "" Then
                Target.Value = NewVal
            Else
                ' Delete cell contents
                If NewVal = "" Then
                    Target.Value = NewVal
                Else
                    ' This IF prevents the same value appearing in the cell multiple times
                    ' If you are happy to have the same value multiple times remove this IF
                    If InStr(Target.Value, NewVal) = 0 Then
                        Target.Value = OldVal & ", " & NewVal
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
        
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Finally, there is a logic flaw at the bottom of your `if` tree. If oldval is not in newval, oldval is not blank and new val is not blank you end up in that final place where it optinally adds a comma. If the that isn't needed then you're in a state where you have run `.Undo` on the change and you haven't set `Target.Value` at all. This might make it so you can't change the contents of a cell to a new value. I'm not sure if you intended that behavior.

Comment: Worked for my primary question. I am sure the logic flaw is unintentionally there. I'll need to think through how to resolve it.